# Bash Nested loops

Tags: bash

I need an output in below format:

Consider for example a sequence of numbers from 1 to 50 in my input file, each number representing a line of data:

```
$ cat input.txt
1
2
3
.
.
.
49
50
```

I want them to be in 5 files, each file having 10 lines:

```
$ cat output1.txt
1
2
.
.
.
9
10

$ cat output2.txt
11
12
.
.
.
19
20
```

And so on. I want to do this via a Bash script, without using the `split` command.

Comment: What exactly should each file have inside of it? Please be more clear.

Comment: example: file_a.txt has 1000 lines each line is of same size. I want them to be split in 100 files each having 10 files using bash script rather than using split command. Hope this make things clear.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your expected output. Also explain why you need this to be done in bash instead of other tools.

Comment: Can you paste sample output ? OR do you want like `seq 10 > file_a,txt` type output

Comment: Seq 1 100 is being generated to a file.txt but i want them to be split into small files consisting  5 lines example:

cat file_a.txt 
1
2
3
4
5  
cat file_b.txt 
6
7
8
9
10

Comment: Comments don't have enough formatting and can be deleted; edit your post to clarify it, please.

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` approach:

```
awk -va=1 '{ print > a; if(NR % 10 ==0){a++} }' input
```

This will produce files `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` and `5`. To make it print to `output1` through 5, use this instead:

```
awk -va=1 '{ print > "output"a; if(NR % 10 ==0){a++} }' input
```

#### Explanation

- `-va=1` : set the variable `a` to `1`.
- `print > "output"a;` : print the current line to a file called `output` and the current value of the variable `a`.
- `if(NR % 10 ==0){a++}` : `NR` is the current line number. So, if `NR` is a multiple of `10` (if `NR` modulo 10 is 0), increment the value of the variable `a` by one. This ensures that the output file's number changes as necessary.

Comment: Very neat `awk` solution, would definitely recommend this over my `head`/`tail` loop answer ! +1

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can do it with `split` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016894/how-to-split-a-large-text-file-into-smaller-files-with-equal-number-of-lines) but if you want to do it with a loop instead:

```
numLines=$(cat input.txt | wc -l)
size=50
n=$(( numLines / size ))

for (( i=0; i<n; i++ )); do
     j=$(( i*size + 1 ))
     tail -n +$j input.txt | head -n $size > output_$i.txt
done
```

In one-liner format :

```
numLines=$(cat input.txt | wc -l); for (( i=0; i<$(( numLines / 50 )); i++ )); \
    do tail -n +$(( i*50 + 1)) input.txt | head -n 50 > output_$i.txt; done
```